# Connection to onedrive

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, onedrive

I am going to migrate files from fileserver to OneDrive for over 1000 accounts. (Can't use migration tool). I got admin rights in OneDrive and can create/edit folders etc.

```
 #Add required references to SharePoint client assembly to use CSOM 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")  

# Specify local folder path
$LocalFolder = "C:\test"

# Specify the User account for an Office 365 global admin in your organization
$AdminAccount = "admin@MY_ACCT_W_PERMS.onmicrosoft.com"
$AdminPass = "MY_SUPA_DUPA_SECRET_PWD"

# Specify User's OneDrive Site URL and Folder name
$OneDriveURL = "https://OurCompany-my.sharepoint.com/personal/name_domain_com"

$DocumentLibrary ="Documents"
$TargetFolderName ='' #Leave empty to target root folder

#Connect and Load OneDrive Library and Root Folder
$SecPwd = $(ConvertTo-SecureString $AdminPass -asplaintext -force) 
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($OneDriveURL) 
$Credentials = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($AdminAccount,$SecPwd) 
$Ctx.credentials = $Credentials
$List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($DocumentLibrary)
$Ctx.Load($List)
$Ctx.Load($List.RootFolder)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

etc...

I am getting error:
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL)
could not look up the realm information for a federated sign-in."

We have MFA in place and I found some suggestion to remove -credentials param from the cmdlet so it will prompt for weblogin, but how???? I am lost. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

ok, it seems related to permissions, looks like admins revoked accidentally my permissions in OneDrive